# Javascript changes dissapear when going back from servlet to JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

Good evening,
I have a form on a JSP page that's connected to a servlet, that form has some dynamic parts using JavaScript like adding a row to a table or adding a text field based on the selected option on a select element, Actually my problem is that I have some validations on the servlet-side, so when I go to servlet to check the (National ID) for example if there's any problem or any violations to my validation I force to get back to the form using :

```
if (dbm.MatchIdNumber(Candidate.getRegNumber(), Candidate.getNationalID()) == false) {
                    out.println("<script>\n"
                            + "     alert('Your National Id does not match your Registration Number');\n"
                            + "</script>");
                    out.println("<script>\n"
                            + "     window.history.go(-1);\n"
                            + "</script>");
                }
```

What happens is when I get back to the form I lose all the JavaScript changes, Which's very important.
I've been reading for a while that using ajax might be the optimal solution for me, but here is my questions:

1. Is there a way to call a java method from JavaScript or JQuery before getting to servlet without using ajax !?!
2. Is there a way to get back from the servlet to the jsp page with the ability to keep all the JavaScript Chages !?
3. If not !!, How to use ajax in my case ?!

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

1. No. JavaScript runs on the user's browser and your Java code runs on your webserver, so basically the only way to communicate between the two is via HTTP requests.
2. If you don't want to use AJAX, you could provide all of the relevant info when you submit the form to the server for validation. You could pass all the info you need to re-generate the form as it was, like which new fields are there and such
3. First, you'll need to add a new webservice to your Java webapp which performs validation. To achieve this, you could either add additional logic to your servlet (so that it looks for a request parameter like "doValidation=1" and performs validation if it's there) or write a different servlet that handles validation itself. You'll need to decide the format it should expect the form data in and how it should return the validation information.

   On your frontend page, you'll need to modify the behavior of the form so that, when you need to do validation, it performs a request to this webservice and passes along the form data. I would probably do this with jQuery and do something like jQuery.ajax(...) and pass the contents of the form as a JSON object.

   When your validation servlet returns data from the ajax call, you'll need to update the form based on the data it provides. If I was doing it, I would probably just have the servlet return a JSON object like {errorMessage:"..."} and I would use jQuery to add an element to the form containing the text of the validation error when it occurs. If the servlet returns an empty string or JSON object or something, I would consider it a validation success.